# The supplied phased action failed with an exception. A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'. Could not read script 'E:\flutter sdk\

Tags: flutter, dart, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-gradle-3.0

I am facing this issue in my Flutter Project while building APK. Can anyone guide me please? I tried every possible solution to solve it but can't solve it.

```
The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.
Could not read script 'E:\flutter sdk\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\app_plugin_loader.gradle' as it does not exist.
```

[A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'. Could not read script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6yxw.png)

I am trying to build APK of my Flutter project. The Flutter SDK path is correct in the environment variables.